# apache url redirect with ID mapped

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

I'm trying to redirect a URL structure using a regular expression in the form of

```
/page_slug/[ID]/
```

to

```
/page_slug/entry/[ID]/?param_1=abc&param_2=xyz
```

I need it to only trigger for a number.

I tried using `(.*)` but that works for everything. I'm not sure how to implement `\d` for a number, as everything I've tried is not working.

Comment: Can you provide real examples and also show what you have tried?

Comment: Which Apache module are you using? If you are having trouble with `\d` then it sounds as if you are trying to use mod_alias `Redirect`? You will need to use `RedirectMatch` or possibly mod_rewrite.